# Default for DateField & display multiple results - Easyadmin 4 with Symfony 7

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I use Symfony 7 with the easyadmin bundle 4 for my new project.
I now have two problems for which I have no solution.

1. I have a DateField for which I would like to set today as the default value, because most times when i add a new entry, i need to chose today as the new date value:

   in configureFields:

   ```
    return [
        yield DateField::new('date')->setColumns(2),
        ...
    ];
   ```
2. I connected some data with my domainlist. Every data can have many domains (ManyToMany). On the index page there is only a 2, but not the 2 individual domains.

   in configureFields:

   ```
    return [
        yield AssociationField::new('domain')->setColumns(6)
        ...
    ];
   ```